# Why if(null) is throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java

I have the following simple code

```
Boolean b = null;
if(b){....}
```

It is throwing a NPE. Do you know what are the JVM/JDK mechanisms that trigger this NPE instead of just returning false ? I must say I did not looked at the bytecode.

Comment: `if` is expecting `true` or `false`, so it's logical that it throws a NullPointerException ...

Comment: It is trying to unbox the `Boolean` object into a `boolean` value. Unboxing `null` throws an NPE. `null` is not a boolean value, so it cannot be used as a condition in Java.

Comment: null does not evaluates to true or false that is why NPE

Comment: It require the call to `b.booleanValue()` -> NPE

Comment: I think even if this question is simple it is a relevant question, so not sure it deserves negative votes

Comment: Thanks @AxelH, I think this is the best answer

Comment: You can use Optional class

Comment: The negative votes are probably due to lack of research.

Comment: I googled a bit and also searched on stackoverflow. Obviously I could have searched a bit more

Comment: @greg Yeah lack of research and it's a duplicate question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Boolean b = null;
if(b){....}
```

This condition will require an unboxing of the `Boolean` to get a `boolean`.

```
if(b.booleanValue() == true)
```

It is basically using `Boolean.booleanValue` giving the `NullPointerException`.

You can prevent this using

```
Boolean b = null;
if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(b)){ //NPE safe
    System.out.println(bool);
}
```

But this is a bit more verbose.

Careful, you don't have 2 states (true/false) but 3 (true/false/null) so you can have something like

```
if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(b)){ 
    System.out.println("true);
} else if(Boolean.FALSE.equals(b)){
    System.out.println("false");
} else {
    System.out.println("null");
}
```

You can also use `Optional`.
A quick and dirty example :

```
Optional.ofNullable(b).ifPresent(bool -> {
    System.out.println(bool);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An `if` statement expects a `boolean`. A `boolean` can only be `true` or `false`, no `null` allowed since it is a **primitive data type** and not an `Object`.

But then there is **auto-boxing**. It's a technique where Java automatically converts primitives into their wrapper objects, so

```
boolean <-> Boolean
int     <-> Integer
double  <-> Double
...
```

whenever needed.

Since those wrapper objects are `Object`s, `null` is a possible value for them. So if you write

```
Boolean b = null;
if (b) { ... }
```

Java knows you are passing a `Boolean` object and tries to unwrap it automatically into its `boolean` representation. Therefore, it calls the method `Boolean#booleanValue` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#booleanValue())). So your code gets converted to something like

```
if (b.booleanValue()) { ... }
```

When evaluating this statement you are trying to call a method on something that is `null`. This is not possible and correctly throws a `NullPointerException`.